# How to show that a problem is well-posed in numerical analysis?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

So I am given the following system of linear equations, for some unknowns $x$ and $y$ and datum $d$
$$
\begin{cases}
x + dy = 1 \newline
dx + y = 0
\end{cases}
$$
The question is what values of $d$ is the problem well-posed? Now I know that well-posed means that the problem admits a unique solution and is continuously dependent of the data $d$. I have computed the solution to be
$$
(x,y)=(\frac{1}{1-d^2}, \frac{d}{d^2 - 1})
$$
which is a unique solution if $d \ne \pm 1$. However, I am unsure how to prove that it is continuously dependent of the data $d$. I have the formal definition

> Let $d \in D$ and the perturbation $\delta d$ such that $d + \delta d$ is also admissible, i.e., $(d + \delta d) \in D$. Let $\delta x$ be such that $F(x + \delta x, d + \delta d) = 0$. Then the solution $x$ depends continuously on the data $d$ if
> $\exists \eta_0, \exists K_0$ such that
> $$
> \|\delta d\| \leq \eta_0 \Rightarrow \|\delta x\| \leq K_0 \|\delta d\|
> $$

However, when I've tried using this the algebra becomes horrible. So is there an easier way to show that the problem is continuously dependent on the data?

Comment: you wrote datum $d$  but your system has just a $b$

Comment: Ah yes sorry. Fixed it now

Comment: The formal definition is invalid in my opinion (the quantifiers seem all out of order), but it seems to just be saying that the function $d \mapsto (x,y)$ (mapping a datum $d$ to the unique corresponding solution $(x,y)$) is continuous.

Comment: So then I guess the answer it that it's well-posed if $d \ne \pm 1$?

Comment: In your case, it means you need to check that the function $d \mapsto (\frac{1}{1-d^2}, \frac{d}{1-d^2})$ is continous on the "admissible domain" $\Bbb{R}\backslash \{\pm 1\}$. This is the case, but proving it directly is tricky. You might be able to take it for granted, depending on the context of you learning this, or you need to apply some basic facts (polynomials are continuous, products and quotients preserve continuity, etc.).